# Heroku: Javascript/MySQL project crashing on request

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, heroku, npm

I have a Heroku API written in JavaScript that reads data from a MySQL database. It previously worked, but now every time I send a request to the API, I get this error:

```
2020-06-17T18:37:13.493711+00:00 app[web.1]: > my_api@0.0.0 start /app
2020-06-17T18:37:13.493712+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2020-06-17T18:37:13.493712+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-17T18:37:14.977800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-17T18:38:40.255982+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:149
2020-06-17T18:38:40.256022+00:00 app[web.1]:     err.fatal = true;
2020-06-17T18:38:40.256023+00:00 app[web.1]:               ^
2020-06-17T18:38:40.256023+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-17T18:38:40.256026+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot create property 'fatal' on string 'SOCKS: Authentication failed'
2020-06-17T18:38:40.256027+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection._handleFatalError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:149:15)
2020-06-17T18:38:40.256027+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection._handleNetworkError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:169:10)
2020-06-17T18:38:40.256027+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SocksConnection.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-06-17T18:38:40.256029+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/socksjs/socks.js:146:18
2020-06-17T18:38:40.256029+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.dataReady (/app/node_modules/socksjs/socks.js:93:13)
2020-06-17T18:38:40.256029+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-06-17T18:38:40.256030+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:556:12)
2020-06-17T18:38:40.256030+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)
2020-06-17T18:38:40.263200+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-06-17T18:38:40.263391+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-06-17T18:38:40.264251+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! my_api@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2020-06-17T18:38:40.264354+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-06-17T18:38:40.264471+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
```

The code in question looks like this:

```
function new_db_connection() {
    var sockConn = new SocksConnection(remote_options, sock_options);
    var dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    user: 'myusername',
    database: 'mydatabase',
    password: 'mypassword',
    stream: sockConn
});
    return [sockConn, dbConnection];
};


router.get('/myrequest', function(req, res, next) {
    new_conn = new_db_connection();
    dbConnection = new_conn[1];
    sockConn = new_conn[0];
    dbConnection.query('SELECT * from mytable', function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({
                "status": 500,
                "error": error,
                "response": null
            }));
            //If there is error, we send the error in the error section with 500 status
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({
                "status": 200,
                "error": null,
                "response": results
            }));
            //If there is no error, all is good and response is 200OK.
        }
        sockConn.dispose();
    });
    dbConnection.end()
});
```

I saw a similar question asked on here and the solution was to close the connection, but I **do** close the connection after each request, so I don't know where the issue is.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using SocksConnection? Could you test with a traditional approach in order to validate is socks is the problem?

Comment: I'm using a third party tool that provides an IP address which I need to have in order to access the db

Comment: It seems the error is in at Socket.dataReady (/app/node_modules/socksjs/socks.js:93:13). Could be due to latency at the moment to retrieve the database parameters, so the mysql client is not able to establish the connection.

Comment: Just below `dbConnection = new_conn[1];` & `sockConn = new_conn[0];` before the query, what do you get if you try console logging both `dbConnection ` and `sockConn`.

Comment: What's in `events.js:315`? It's trying to call `_handleNetworkError` on a string but that function is expecting an error object. After resolving that it will be easier for you to tell where the authentication error is coming from. Also, where is the source code for `SocksConnection`?

Comment: Is the MySQL hosted through an online service? Sometimes they refresh their authentication configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this

```
        sockConn.dispose();
    });
    dbConnection.end()
});
```

in this

```
        sockConn.dispose();
        dbConnection.end()
    });
});
```

**Edit:** reading better the error, it could be the problem is some where else.

Looking at the string `'SOCKS: Authentication failed'`, could it be that you or the `SocksConnection` remote endpoint changed something in the authentication?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have broken it down to debug it, and it does connect to the db without any issues - the error is thrown when I send the query to the db

Comment: I tried putting a `console.log` after the `dbConnection.end()` and it does show up, so now I don't even know what to think

Comment: But have you tried the change I proposed before my edit @JessicaChambers ?

Comment: I did, but it didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the answer provided by @daniele Rici you need to end your connection properly; however, fixing this will not solve your initial question.

The issue is not with your code. **Your issue is with connection configuration**.

> 'fatal' on string 'SOCKS: Authentication failed'

Means there was an error with authentication.

```
var sockConn = new SocksConnection(remote_options, sock_options);
```

under the assumention you are using ther npm package socksjs from https://openbase.io/js/socksjs

It is documented that the correct way to initialize a sockjs connection is by doing the following:

```
var sock = new SocksConnection(remote_options, sock_options); 
var sock = SocksConnection.connect(remote_options, sock_options, connect_handler);
```